# Display original typescript file when debugging typescript using node-inspector CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node, node-debugger

Is there any means of having the node-inspector CLI (or any CLI-based debugger) display the original typescript file when debugging?

For example, for debugging typescript, I usually run something like: `nodemon -e ts -w src -x "tsc -p . && node inspect ./dist/file.js"`. This works, but it debugs the transpiled javascript.

To work around this, I tried using `ts-node` like so: `nodemon -e ts -w src -x "node inspect -r ts-node/register src/file.ts"`. Still, the debugger will show the transpiled JS.

`sourcemap: true` in `tsconfig` does not help, either.

Comment: Does it have to be node inspector ? Can you use VSCode or WebStorm ?

Comment: I'm looking for any solution that can be run on the command-line without dealing with a GUI.

Comment: What version of ts-node you are using ?

Comment: Using ts-node version 8.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest ts-node you should be able to do something like below:-

```
nodemon -e ts -w src -x "node --inspect -r ts-node/register src/file.ts"
```

Or use `--inspect-brk`

Comment: I've tried that too but if using the node-inspector debugger to attach to the process it still steps through compiled JavaScript.